# How can I replicate this T-SQL update statement via SnowSQL?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is been breaking my brain for a while... the following code is T-SQL, how can I replicate this it SnowSQL?

```
UPDATE TABLEONE
SET ACS_LOCATION_ID = (
SELECT TOP 1
    PBS_LOCATOR_ID
FROM
    TABLETWO A
WHERE
    A.TICKETNUMBER = TABLEONE.TICKETNUMBER
    AND
    A.PBS_LOCATOR_ID = TABLEONE.PBS_LOCATOR_ID 
    AND
    A.TRIPNUMBER = TABLEONE.TRIPNUMBER
AND
    A.ORIGIN_ID = TABLEONE.ORIGIN_ID
);
```

I cannot simply replace 'TOP 1' with 'LIMIT 1' as it results in an unsupported subquery.

Inevitably I end up including additional columns in the subquery, or a require a window function with an order clause that I do not have a definition for (only limit 1 in the original T-SQL).

Or I end up with something like this:

```
UPDATE  TABLEONE
SET  ACS_LOCATION_ID = TABLETWO.PBS_LOCATOR_ID 
FROM
TABLETWO
WHERE
TABLETWO.TICKETNUMBER = TABLEONE.TICKETNUMBER
AND
TABLETWO.PBS_LOCATOR_ID  = TABLEONE.PBS_LOCATOR_ID 
AND
TABLETWO.TRIPNUMBER = TABLEONE.TRIPNUMBER
AND
TABLETWO.ORIGIN_ID = TABLEONE.ORIGIN_ID
;
```

or

```
UPDATE TABLEONE
SET  ACS_LOCATION_ID = (SELECT PBS_LOCATOR_ID FROM TABLETWO LIMIT 1)
FROM
TABLETWO
WHERE
TABLETWO.TICKETNUMBER = TABLEONE.TICKETNUMBER
AND
TABLETWO.PBS_LOCATOR_ID  = TABLEONE.PBS_LOCATOR_ID 
AND
TABLETWO.TRIPNUMBER = TABLEONE.TRIPNUMBER
AND
TABLETWO.ORIGIN_ID = TABLEONE.ORIGIN_ID
;
```

There is no SME who can give input on why the original code is written the way it is, I also do not have access to the SQL Server instance so I cannot compare script results.

Feel like I'm losing my mind, any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: As your SQL doesn’t have an ORDER BY, TOP 1 will produce a random record, assuming there is more than one to return - which doesn’t make a lot of sense. If it will only ever return one record then TOP 1 is unnecessary

Comment: Also, your first SQL seems to use an inconsistent set of references in the WHERE clause. Are these typos?

Comment: My apologies, I have updated the references in the WHERE clause - they were typos. I totally agree that without an ORDER BY, the TOP 1 will be random.

Unfortunately this is the legacy code I have been asked to migrate and there is no one that can explain why TOP 1 is included (and why there is no ORDER BY).

Comment: Ok - but presumably you can look at your data and work out whether it could return more than one record and therefore whether TOP is required?